# Projects quota for Google Developers Console

Tags: google-api-console

When I try to add new projects to my [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), I get this message:

```
You have exceeded the quota for project creations per day.
```

I have a similar error when accepting a new project invitation:

```
You have no more apps available to accept this invitation.
```

We have created or invited about 25 projects, and as a software company we need more than that.
Is there any way to lift this limitation?

Comment: Possible dulplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676900/google-developers-console-project-creation-quota